# React-Native Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, manifest, intercom

From today I am getting the below error while building the app from the android studio:

```
/Users/macm60/Desktop/mobile-app/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:15:13-72 Error:
Attribute provider#androidx.core.content.FileProvider@authorities value=(com.verygoodsecurity.vgsshow.provider) from [com.verygoodsecurity:vgsshow:1.2.0] AndroidManifest.xml:15:13-72
is also present at [io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:15.1.6] AndroidManifest.xml:121:13-72 value=(com.today.development.IntercomFileProvider).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-21:20 to override.

/Users/macm60/Desktop/mobile-app/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:44:17-55 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource value=(@xml/file_paths) from [:react-native-blob-util] AndroidManifest.xml:44:17-55
    is also present at [io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:15.1.6] AndroidManifest.xml:126:17-60 value=(@xml/intercom_file_paths).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
```

Last Friday app was successfully built from android studio.

This is related to `@intercom/intercom-react-native 5.1.1` library manifest file.
Let me know if anyone has an idea for this.

I have posted a temporary solution but let me know if have a permanent solution.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this? I'm having the same issue with version 5.2.0. I think the problem is with the Intercom-sdk-base:15.1.6

Comment: Not yet, let me know if you have any.

Comment: @jose Villalobos, since when are you facing this error?

Comment: @JoseVillalobos you are right, this error is getting after `Intercom-sdk-base:15.1.6`. They recently launched this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your project add below code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  <!-- this line-->
          package="com.xyz">
```

In `<Application>` tag add below:

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  tools:node="replace">     <!-- this line-->
```

Comment: However, this causes another problem in my Flutter project.
It makes crash with FirebaseSDK. 

Cause: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()'

Answer (score 1):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `<Application>` tag of your project add below code:

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
  tools:replace="android:authorities">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/intercom_file_paths"
    tools:replace="android:resource" />
</provider>
```

probably this is better solution then just `tools:node="replace"` on `application` level

Answer (score 0):

Intercom recently launched  `Intercom-sdk-base` `15.1.6` due to this this error is coming.

If anyone is facing this issue then, here is a temporary solution:

Goto -

> node_modules/@intercom/intercom-react-native/android/build.gradle

then change this
`implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:15.1.+'`

to below:

> `implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:15.1.0'`

or you can use any other version but not use `15.1.6`.